# How do I configure mongoosastic (ElasticSearch) with heroku?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Im using node.js and mongoosastic to do the search. I'm wondering because this article only specify using with Rails

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai
It's using bonsai.

How do I Run ElasticSearch as in the local, but on heroku?

in local, I will simply run this command `elasticsearch`, but how do I do it on Heroku?